# What did Lore get from collaborating with the Crystalline Entity?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the Next Generation episode [*DataLore*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Datalore_%28episode%29) we are introduced to the Data's brother Lore and the Crystalline Entity. Through the episode it is shown that Lore had a partnership of sorts with the Entity, having been responsible for it attacking the colony Omicron Theta and planning to feed the Enterprise crew to it.

While it is true that Lore held little regard for humans, believing them to be a lesser species, he doesn't come off as someone who would help another for no personal gain. So what did Lore receive from the Crystalline Entity in return for leading it to, or bringing to it, sources of food. Was Lore doing this simply for the feel good feeling of killing people, or was there some other motive?

Comment: I think it was revenge against the colonists, protection, and to sate his thirst for sadism, which seems to be his main flaw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC he used the CE to get revenge on the colonists for having him deactivated. He thought they were all jealous of his abilities but they were really just afraid of him because Lore saw them all as inferior.
In a later episode (Brothers), Noonian Soong reveals to Data and Lore that the colonists were terrified of Lore as he was malfunctioning.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but if Lore was de-activated, then how did he do anything?  It seems difficult to imagine that a de-activated android could find a new species, learn to communicate with it, and conspire with it in a revenge plot. Not saying that revenge isn't a good motive, but there seems to be something missing here.

Comment: @Zoredache: Believe it or not, I was thinking the same thing on the drive home! Lore would have had to terrify all the colonists, the colonists complain, Lore makes deal with CE, Lore gets deactivated and then the CE eats everyone but Dr Soong. Yeah, there's probably more to that story...

Comment: @Zoredache -  Not a silly question at all. This answer is most unsatisfactory. How would he communicate with the Crystalline Entity if he was deactivated? Obviously he communicated, then was *later deactivated* (and neatly stored), then the entity arrived.

Answer (score 7):

### Lore needs to use the Crystalline Entity to kill the colonists as he's unable to disobey his creator; Dr. Noonian Soong.

We know that Lore was built with a more "*human-like*" personality than Data as well as being exposed to the scanned memories of the colonists on Omicron Theta. Whether this process is what pushed him over the edge of sanity or whether he was always going to go insane is not explained but regardless of the cause, Dr Soong identifies that the colonists were terrified of Lore and petitioned Soong to deactivate him, something that he was able to do [with ease](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/177.txt).

> Soong stands and turns to Lore.
>
> **SOONG :**   *You were the first. You meant
>   as much to me as Data ever did. But you were unstable. The colonists
>   weren't envious of you, they were afraid of you. You were unstable.*

There's no canon reference as to when Lore first learned to communicate with the [Crystalline entity](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Crystalline_Entity) but what's apparent is that somewhere between the date of his creation and his ultimate deactivation, he made contact with entity and drew it to the colony with the main intention of killing the colonists, **something that Lore can't do because of the block on his free will**

> **SOONG :** (continuing to Data) *Lore is far from the maniacal android you have made him out to be. In any case, **he'll obey me. He
>   always did.***

The Crystal Entity appears to be both sentient and intelligent, responding to direct verbal commands given by Lore over a communication channel. Since the entity isn't bound by the same restrictions as Lore (e.g. to obey Soong) it makes perfect sense that Lore would have contracted out the murders to a **third-party hitman**.

[image: Crystalline Entity]

Comment: Is there any canon evidence that Lore had this sort of "block on his free will" that prevented direct violence, besides the line "he'll obey me. He always did"? That line could be interpreted as just Soong trusting that Lore will treat him as a father and be obedient, not an Asimov's-laws-of-robotics type programmed constraint (wouldn't Asimov's first law forbid inciting violence?), and I think the latter interpretation is pretty clearly invalidated in the episode "Brothers" where at the end Lore grabs Soong's wrist and throws him across the room, giving him what proves to be a fatal injury.

Comment: @hypnosifl - The fact that he can be summoned,  the fact that he sits on command. Those suggest to me that it's taken a considerable amount of time for him to get around his programming to  the point that he can contemplate direct violence. Note that he can only do this after getting the emotion chip

Comment: I agree that Lore is using the CE as a 'hitman' but I don't agree that he is unable to disobey his creator, necessarily. Instead, I would point out that it would be dangerous and time-consuming for Lore to kill all the colonists himself; though strong and resilient, he is not invincible.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding was that Lore used the CE to take revenge from the colonists, but it is not clear then why he called it back to feast on the Enterprise.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Any further information or citations that you can add in support of your answer will improve it, and make it more likely to be accepted.