# How did Lore come into a relationship with the Crystalline Entity?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Does anything speak to how a lone android could have made an alliance with the Crystalline Entity? The Entity was apparently brought to Omicron Theta by Lore, but how did Lore even know of the Entity to do this?

Presumably they met at some point, or perhaps the Entity was known to have been in that system in the past, and so Lore figured out a way to attract it to the planet.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question doesn't touch on how Lore originally contacted the Entity. It's just assumed.

Comment: My [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49837/20774) specifically speaks to this question ("*There's no canon reference as to when Lore first learned to communicate with the Crystalline entity*") which is why I marked it as a dupe.

Comment: *"And let us toast also the great
   Crystal Entity... with which I
   learned to communicate. Before
   Doctor Soong disassembled me, I
   earned its gratitude by revealing
   the way to the colonists.*" - And that's your lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to divide this into two sections:

### 1: How did Lore know about the Entity?

I suspect the Entity had previously visited Omicron Theta.  Remember in 'Datalore', we see children's pictures of the Crystalline Entity and all the havoc it had wreaked *on the planet*.  How could the children have made this drawings unless there were **two** visits by the Crystalline Entity?  In the final one, pretty much everyone was killed.

I think we can therefore safely assume the Crystalline Entity had been to Omicron Theta *at least twice*.

So, as to how Lore learnt about it, **he probably was activated when the Crystalline Entity visited the first time**.

### 2: How did Lore know how to communicate with the Entity?

The important thing to remember is that this was a science colony.  If we accept my above proposition that the Entity had visited Omicron Theta more than once, chances are that there would have been some sensory data collected on it.  Because Lore is pretty smart, he may well have figured out for himself how to communicate with it.  In 'Silicon Avatar', we learn that graviton pulses can be used to communicate with the Entity; Lore probably figured this out.  Admittedly, there is a discrepancy between 'Datalore' and 'Silicon Avatar', as in the former, Lore appears to speak using natural language to the Entity, but we could assume that Lore had programmed the Universal Translator to translate his language into meaningful graviton pulses.

Comment: Surely the children drew the pictures while they were cowering, waiting for the crystalline entity to hoover them up. We see that its "beam" isn't very wide. Even if it criss-crossed the planet at 1000mph, it would still take days to kill everyone. Needlessly creating a second visit makes little sense.

Comment: It would seem more likely that Lore encountered it while actively scanning the sky (and hence how and why he led it to the colony). Perhaps he was hoping to get off the rock before he got disassembled.

Comment: @Richard but even if it took a fair while for the Entity to cross the colony, it seems unlikely to me that it would become the subject of children's drawings - how would they know that it was attacking people necessarily if they hadn't witnessed it; it's not the sort of thing parents would be actively describing to their children

Comment: @Richard we see the Entity is capable of warp speeds and we get the impression that Lore was first assembled then work started on Data, which would have taken a while to build and program him

Comment: My sequence of events; Entity hanging in the sky (and highly visible), children and parents run scared, everyone cowers in caves while kids draw pictures to keep them quiet, entity eventually hoovers everyone up.

Comment: @Richard indeed that is a plausible account. I'm still standing by mine though (I was there after all )

Comment: I always assumed that the colonists had shields or other protections and Lore lowered the shields for the entity. No proof, just made sense to me.